# How to pass post results from one html to other html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I want to pass results (return value of POST) from one page into other embedded page, and I don't know how can I do it.

The structures look like:
main html page (Welcome.html) which has ej2 file (Buttom.html):

Welcome.html:

```
<html>

    <body>

     <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>       
     <script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){          

                  $("#submit").click(function(){ 

                    xhr.open("POST", "/addGrade", true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                    data = // logic to get the data (i skipped adding this part)
                    xhr.send(data);
                    xhr.onloadend = function () {
                         // HERE I WANT TO PASS THE RESULTS TO Buttom.html
                    };

                }); // click on submit
         }); // ready


      </script> 

     <form id="gradeForm">
            <p>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </p>            
            <p>
                <label>Grade:</label>
                <input type="text" name="grade" id="grade" value="100">
            </p>
            <p>
                 <button type="button" id="submit" >submit</button>
            </p>            
    </form>

  <div> 
    <%include Buttom.html%>
  </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Buttom.html:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>


<script type = "text/javascript"  src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script type = "text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){          
     }); // ready
</script>   


<p id="ppp">
    <!-- Here I want to add the results -->
<p>


</body>
```

How can I pass the results from POST (in welcome.html) to Buttom.html (i.e into function of js in Buttom.html) ?

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery this would be much simpler using `$.ajax` or `$.post` and following the examples in the documentation

Comment: HTML isn't dynamic like this. You'd have to either use a server technology, or store the data with JavaScript in a cookie or the equivalent, but I'd recommend against this

Comment: Am I missing something? Including an HTML file, complete with head and body sections, into a DIV element server side will not produce valid HTML.

Comment: if your data is not sensitive or confidential you can you url.

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome.HTML**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){          

                  $("#submit").click(function(){ 

                    xhr.open("POST", "/addGrade", true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
                    data = // logic to get the data (i skipped adding this part)
                    xhr.send(data);
                    xhr.onloadend = function () {
                         // If your data is big then use cookies or create form and send it to another page

                    var url = "YourPage?data=" + encodeURIComponent(YOUR_DATA);
                    window.location.href = url;



                    };

                }); // click on submit
         }); // ready
```

**ON Buttom.html:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  


 var queryString = new Array();
    $(function () {
        if (queryString.length == 0) {
            if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (queryString["name"] != null) {
             // YOUR CODE   

        }
    });
```

});

Comment: seems that it doesn't work. I'm getting "Cannot GET /Buttom.html"

Comment: Seriously, Bottom.html is your page so give the exact path of it.

Comment: @user3668129 I have updated the answer please check and let me know if its working ?